# JS Dropdown menu bugs out on height toggle

Tags: jquery, hover

I have created an expanding menu which all works fine, however instead of the sub-menus working by the instant `show()`; & `hide()`;  I want to use `.animate({height : toggle})`

This is all well and good when the menu buttons are triggered on click, but obviously the client needs them to be triggered on hover.

This causes the menu to bug out and repeatedly trigger the action. I have tried changing the trigger to mouseenter etc and splitting the script from action and callback to two separate actions but with no luck. I'm sure there must be an easy way to possibly unbind or delay the trigger but really struggling to work this one out.

```
$('li.tab-drop-down').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').animate ({height: "toggle"}, 250);
    $(this).addClass("li-open");            
    $(this).find('a.tab-link').addClass("tab-drop-hover");
    $(this).find('span').addClass("open");          
    },
    function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').animate ({height: "toggle"}, 0);
    $(this).removeClass("li-open");                     
    $(this).find('a.tab-link').removeClass("tab-drop-hover");
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("open");                       
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5GeMd/

Many thanks in advance SO !!
Chris

Comment: I think that's going to be really troublesome. The problem is that when you leave from one `li` to another, as the first one's still being closed, it pulls the second one up as well, and then you're not hover the second one. Then you're getting on and off that `li` in an infinite loop. The only think I can think of is unbinding the hover event until the animation is over.

Comment: your code is totally crowded.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**jQuery.stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) in order to stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

**Example ::**

```
$('li.tab-drop-down').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true);
    //existing stuff
   },
   function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true);
    //existing stuff
   });
});
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: I've tried implementing this and also doesn't seem to be working for me. Itay, I attempted to integrate an unbind as this seems the logical solution but I'm not sure how I would make this only occur until the animation is over? Many thanks all for your contributions.